# Sequelize specify SQL type inside of replacements object for raw query

Tags: sequelize.js

Let me preface by saying I am not using Sequelize as an ORM I am just using it to execute raw queries against our MSSQL database.

Is there a way to specify a SQL data type inside of the replacements object? Currently what is happening is Sequelize is trying to convert `startDate` and `endDate` to a NVARCHAR when the column in the database is a SMALLDATETIME. Because of the conversion to NVARCHAR it is creating the following error:
`RequestError: The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.`

I have the following Sequelize query:

```
await sequelize.query(
      `
        INSERT INTO Ledger.PostingPeriods
          (
            messageId,
            PeriodId,
            Name,
            [Active],
            [Open],
            StartDate,
            EndDate
          )
        VALUES
          (
            :messageId,
            :periodId,
            :name,
            :active,
            :open,
            :startDate,
            :endDate
          )
      `,
      {
        replacements: {
          active,
          startDate,
          endDate,
          messageId,
          periodId,
          open,
          name,
        },
      }
    );
```

Comment: what type do `startDate ` and `endDate` have?

Comment: Did you try `bind` instead of `replacements`? Is there any difference?